# Блоки отображаются поверх полосы прокрутки страницы

Tags: css

знатоки. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: блоки `div` отображаются поверх **полосы прокрутки страницы**, когда у них стоит `position: fixed`. Например: шапка сайта. Но `z-index` тут не причем, я проверял.
Так же `width: 100%` при `position: fixed` работает как `width: 100vw`.
Такое отображение усложняет работу и портит вид сайта. Что делать?

Comment: а можно взглянуть как это выглядит?

Comment: Zhihar, да, конечно! https://zientenin.github.io/schoolProject/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**вариант 1:**

1. высоту блока `main` выставить точно

   ```
    height: calc(100vh - 9vh);
   ```

хотя высоту плашки header делать через относительную высоту как-то не очень - могут полезть артефакты

2. блоку `main` добавить свойство

   ```
    overflow: auto;
   ```

в результате прокрутка будет не у всего `body`, а только у блока `main`

**вариант 2:**

сделать `header` липким:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp

**P.S.**

вообще перекрытие прокруток - это особенность браузеров
в мобильном браузере прокрутка видна на `fixed` блоке

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне такие варианты не подходят. Проблему решил просто переместив все свойства с этого файла в другой и подключив его. Магия!